# Programmatically determining if a Racket package is installed

Tags: package, racket, raco

Is there any programmatic way to determine if a package has been installed?

I know about `raco pkg show`, but it only seems to return a string with information about the scope that is installed. For example, if I run it from the command line:

```
$ raco pkg show frog
Installation-wide:
 Package  Checksum                Source
 frog     13fbe6b0...             clone...tt/frog/master
User-specific for installation "development":
 [none]
```

While I could try to parse this result, is there currently a more straightforward way to programmatically determine if a package is installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#lang racket
(require pkg/lib)

(installed-pkg-names)
```

In general, [`pkg/lib`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/pkg/lib.html) is the library that `raco pkg` uses.